# How does the ship object know to get displayed centred at the bottom of the main screen surface?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

These are the relevant source files:

**1. ship.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pygame

class Ship(object):
    """A class to manage the ship."""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

**2. alien_invasion.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pygame
from sys import exit
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion(object):
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game"""
        while True:
            # Watch for keyboard and mouse events. ** The Event Loop **
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop
            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
            self.ship.blitme()

            # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

Running `alien_invasion.py` produces the following output...[image]
...which is the desired output. I just don't understand how the ship's `rect` is positioned (correctly) centered at the bottom when the `Ship.blitme()` method takes parameters `image` and `rect` (and not `rect.midbottom`). To my understanding, this doesn't use the `self.rect.midbottom` attribute anywhere to draw the image on screen after defining it.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an instance of the ship class, you move its rect to the bottom middle of the screen with `self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom`. This moves `rect.x` and `rect.y` as well, so when you blit the ship with the rect, it is already positioned right